# Good term for a business partner and competitor?

Tags: word-choice, neologisms, portmanteau-words

In our line of work we often work with other companies as partners on some jobs, and then compete against them on other jobs.  So they are partners and competitors.  Is there a good term for this, along the lines of "frenemies"?

Comment: Someone with whom you engage in "co-opetition"?

Comment: This feels like it's about to turn into a "bikeshed" type of question. Is there a way we can make this into something where everyone won't have an opinion?

Answer (score 6):

On the theory that one should keep one's friends close, and one's enemies closer, the academic world uses the term ***Colleague*** for precisely the relationship you describe, as well as others.

Comment: I don't know if that was the intention on your part, but it made me laugh! I've always understood that in the academic (as opposed to the business) world, *colleagues* is as likely to mean *enemies* as *friends*.

Comment: "If you want to tell people the truth, make them laugh, otherwise they'll kill you." -- Oscar Wilde

Comment: [Always tell the truth, but **don't always be telling** the truth](http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=AbJ1tVGmiTgC&pg=PA808&lpg=PA808&dq=%22always+tell+the+truth,+but+don't+always+be+telling+the+truth%22&source=bl&ots=1FCy865k7t&sig=X1iLRPIcjXdCPx6sx9UaVGOTi3k&hl=en&sa=X&ei=Af_UUKvQI-Sc0QXOuICoAw&ved=0CDkQ6AEwAQ#v=onepage&q=%22always%20tell%20the%20truth%2C%20but%20don't%20always%20be%20telling%20the%20truth%22&f=false) (I've often been castigated with that one! :)

Comment: I don't think _colleague_ works with _companies_.

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe that there's any term such as *frenemy* that encapsulates the ideas of both *partner* and *competitor* when it comes to companies. You could perhaps choose from some of the more non-committal related terms such as:

- [Peer](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/peer)
- [Associate](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/associate)
- [Affiliate](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/affiliate)

On second thought, I suppose that only *peer* could be construed as completely neutral. But there you have it.

Answer (score 1):

Since you have invoked the [portmanteau-words] (0 followers) I will suggest:

[Compartnitor](http://www.deepchip.com/items/0467-11.html)

Comment: I was hoping I would get credit for creating this word but a web search shows otherwise.