# Is "I don't work here" literal or does it mean "I am not an employee of this establishment"?

Tags: sentence, ambiguity, semantics

Part of my work involves visiting retail establishments during business hours.  Often, when mistaken for an employee of the store, I am asked a question about where to find something in the store, to which I politely respond, "I'm sorry, I don't work here".

But I got to thinking, I *am* working, and I *am* "here".  I know that I could be more precise with a more verbose reply, but is my quick, convenient response truthful?  Conversely, it would not be true to say, "I work here", right?

Comment: If you want to be more precise you could say I don't work for this company. That's the regular meaning of the quick phrase "I don't work here" anyway. Phrases of convenience are just that. They are not meant to be precise. I would say "I don't work here" even if I did work there but was on a day off; rather than explaining my rostering arrangements to a stranger that couldn't care less.

Comment: Kant says if someone who wants to murder your mother asks where your mother is, you're morally obliged to tell the truth regardless of the consequences: your mother dies. Even a consequentialist, who'd say that you should lie to the would-be murderer if you want to save your mother's life, would tell you that the inconvenience caused by lying to the questioner in this case (were you actually an employee of that store or by chance knew the answer to the question) is probably sufficiently inconsequential to not worry about being truthful, unless the Q is "Where's the restroom? I'm gonna puke."

Comment: I would tell Kant's murderer, truthfully, "I don't want to give you that information" and the store-visitor "I'm not a store employee" or "I don't work here" because to me they mean the same thing, but if you don't think they do then use the first one.

Comment: @K: "I don't want to give you that information" would get you killed, so that's not a choice; nor did Kant allow that choice in his example. My response was shock that being truthful in the OP's situation was so important. I'd be helpful if I could, but wouldn't volunteer unnecessary information.

Comment: @Chris: Are you serious? If you happened to be in the store where you normally worked (and thus should know where everything is), you wouldn't even give a customer directions because it was your day off? What about when you *are* working, but you're on your lunch break? If I were the store manager, I surely wouldn't want guys like that on the payroll!

Comment: @Fred: Sorry, but I think this is Not Constructive. You know perfectly well what standard practice is in such situations, since you follow it. In the more general context, *work* (here, or anywhere) means different things to different people. Lots of people work without getting paid, many others get paid for doing things they'd probably pay to do anyway if market conditions changed. In your context, you don't work *"at a job which includes directing customers around this store"*, which is all *"here"* needs to mean.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: I was thinking more about the context where the person needs usual staff help etc. Not if they obviously need to find a toilet. Business doesn't want an employee on day off possibly performing in a capacity as if working. It's an insurance thing. Also, if I was by chance at the store where I worked I wouldn't want to end up looking for stock when not officially working. That's why you have the day off. Or would you as an employee on day off first say "yes I work here" only to disappoint the customer when you can't do things and have to explain yourself. Awkward.

Comment: @Chris: Fair enough. The insurance issue is a good point. I was just thinking of, say, a customer in the supermarket asking "Which aisle are the taco shells in?" Which in the UK late at night is likely to be met by a blank stare even from the guys who *are* at work, since many of them are just immigrant shelf-stackers who barely speak English.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I changed the question in an effort to make it more constructive.  I always try to speak truthfully to people, even when it doesn't matter.  When I considered my standard reply, I questioned whether it was technically the truth.  I thought that asking the question here may shed some light onto nuances of the grammar or definitions that I had not considered.

Comment: @Fred: Well, as you can see from the interchange between me and Chris, even if you use a *lot* more words, there's plenty of scope for misunderstanding. Plus I think there's a limit to how far you can take the idea of *speak truthfully*. Not least because you might have to avoid perfectly normal metaphoric usages, but there's also the maxim [Always tell the truth, but don't always be **telling** the truth](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/95127/2637). Sometimes it's better to just go with the flow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While *I don't work here* means to most people *I don't work for this store*, you could say

> I don't work for the store
>   I'm not an employee of the store
>   I'm not employed here
>   I'm not on staff here
>   I'm not on the staff

You also could say

> I'm not an employee
>   I'm not on staff

While most people are employees or staff somewhere, those statements are not generally taken as absolutes, but are understood to imply *here*.

Comment: bib, I like your Suggestion #2 best. Also, one can also solve this problem by providing more information; for example, if I was stocking chips at the Albertson's supermarket, I might say, "Sorry, I don't work for Albertson's; I work for Frito-Lay." Also, for the sake of politeness, it never hurts to add something like, "I'd be glad to help you, if I knew the answer to your question" – that makes it sound less like you're giving the person a cold shoulder.

Answer (score 5):

"I don't work here" can indeed mean both things, but in your situation, you would not be misunderstood, so you should stick to it for brevity.

Comment: Yes. Didn't someone say "Context is all-important"? This is a wicked answer.